# socket.io emit function server side only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to develop a real time canvas game, i have some code that has the basic functionality i need but not using node or socket.io

---

how would I emit this function to all clients?

```
 function init()
    {
         numShapes = 10;
         shapes = [];
         drawScreen(); 
         ctx= canvas.getContext('2d'); 
         setInterval(draw,10);
         makeShapes();
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a9b3rm5u/5/

---

I am now trying to add a real time element but cannot understand socket.emit. How would I emit the balls from the server to all the clients? then use client side code for the click events?

Comment: If you are looking to sync the drawing of the circles on the clients based on position information from the server, best to stream position data through the socket and let the client draw the data.

Comment: But the circles need to be the same on all clients canvas? but i should send the movement data to the client then the draw shape on client side? how would i achieve this?

Comment: Stream the data: `[{ id: 'circle1' x: 10, y: 40, radius: 10 }]`.

Comment: Why not using node or socket.io. Is there a specific server environment you are looking to engineer this on?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to emit.

I first suggest you look at the chat example on their website, http://socket.io/get-started/chat/, to see how to set up socket.io in your code.

There's info on how to set up Node.js and Socket.io, both of which you'll need in order to use `socket.emit`.

Your concern about client *and* server side interaction isn't an issue. You're able to do only one or both.

You might have something that looks like:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('coordinates', {x: /* your shape's x data */, y: /* your shape's y data */);
});
```

Comment: I have set up a node server with socket and express, so i should just send the x and y coordinates? but if i had more than one shape? and they moved? sorry my knowledge is pretty lacking, just cant get my head around it with the examples i have seen.

Comment: @Noobcoder go do some research on looping through arrays and objects. To capture movement, you'll have to update the `emit` every so often, using either an event or by time intervals.

Answer (score 0):

On your server, if the server has the ball then you can get that ball and emit it to each connected client by:

```
io.emit('ballMove', {x: /*x coordinate of ball*/, y: /*y coordinate of ball*/});
```

On your client socket, you must listen for 'ballMove' which is emitted by the server.

something like:

```
socket.on('ballMove', function(data){
    //get the x and y passed by server from the data argument

    //update the clients local ball with the x & y coordinate passed by the server
    ball.x = data.x;
    ball.y = data.y; 
});
```

if you want sockets to broadcast their local ball's coordinates to other clients except on the socket that emitted it then you can:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('ballMove', { x: ball.x, y:ball.y});
```

all connected clients on the server listening to `ballMove` will receive the data except on the socket who emitted the event.